# Setting counter value back to initial in class

Tags: java, class

```
public class DecreasingCounter {
    private int value;  // instance variable that remembers the value of the counter
    int valueInitial;            

    public DecreasingCounter(int valueAtStart) {
        this.value = valueAtStart;
    }  

    public void reset(){
        this.value = 0;
    }    

    public void setInitial(){
        this.valueInitial = 0;
    }
}
```

I need to change the value back to what it was in `DecreasingCounter(x);` with `setInitial();` using an object variable, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is what `valueInitial` is for :

```
public DecreasingCounter(int valueAtStart) {
    this.valueInitial = valueAtStart;
    this.value = valueAtStart;
}

public void setInitial(){
    this.value = this.valueInitial;
}
```

You store the initial value in the constructor (assigning to `this.valueInitial`) and restore it in `setInitial()`.

You don't want to set `this.valueInitial` to `0`, since that will cause you to lose the initial value that was set in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable to hold a current number.
All your fields will "remember" their value (unlike variables created in the functions/methods).
You should store your initial value in valueInitial and then only tamper with the value-variable.
Like this:

```
public class DecreasingCounter {
private int value;  // instance variable that remembers the value of the counter
int valueInitial;            

public DecreasingCounter(int valueAtStart) {
    this.valueInitial = valueAtStart;
    this.value=this.valueInitial;
}  

public void reset(){
    this.value = 0; //Not sure what you want to do here
}

public void countDown(){
    this.value--;
}  

public void setInitial(){
    this.value = this.valueInitial;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### try this

```
    public class DecreasingCounter
    {
      private int value;  // instance variable that remembers the value of the counter
      int valueInitial;

      public DecreasingCounter(int valueAtStart) 
      {
        this.valueInitial = valueAtStart;
        this.value = valueAtStart;
      }

      public void reset()
      {
        this.value = 0;
      }

      public void setInitial()
      {
        this.value = this.valueInitial;
      }
    }
```

#### In your code you try to assign value 0 to the setIntial() method, so it set to 0, so you loose intial value i.e valueAtStart. instead of this you assign **this.valueInitial** to the setInitial() method.